# save crystal report document type to database and retrieve it later

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, oracle11g, crystal-reports

i have a variable which is
Dim UCRpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReport.Engine.ReportDocument

i can do this with session variable like
session("Test") = UCRpt
and then retrieve it later. This help with paging, exporting, printing. If i don't the report will query the database all over again everytime user go to next page, or print or export.

Because my report are big, doing session variable is not the best solution.

So i thought of storing the UCRpt into a column in the database and retrieve it later. I have searched google and found nothing. Is there a way to do this? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: If i don't the report will query the database all over again everytime user go to next page, or print or export` this sounds like some coding logical errors in your `WebPages Page_Load` event are you handling / coding for `Post_Backs` properly.. can't tell without seeing your code exactly..

Comment: this is where it states that you have to use session to avoid post back http://scn.sap.com/thread/2095092

Comment: I think that you are missing the point.. every button click for example in a web page will trigger a postback.. which will trigger the `Page_Load` event.. unless you are writing some `Ajax or javascript, or using jquery` to get around that ..then what you have posted really has no validity in my opinion.. how about posting what code you have to save all of us from the guessing game..? :)

Comment: if you are going to post an article in regards to doing that without using postback then the next logical thing would be to refactor your code to work off of the example code provided in that link to work with your use case..

Comment: i'm not asking for post back. i'm asking to save the report document to database

Comment: I know what you are asking ...ok can you create a custom class of your own to save / insert the data into your database..? if session object doesn't work can you create a class object that mimics the same structure of the database table etc...? there are many ways to quickly save data to a table from one format to another ..`XML, Json,etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ReportDocument.SaveAs method to save the report to a file and upload this file to the database. In order to save the data with the report you need to use "Save Data with Report" option in Crystal. There should be a way to do this programmatically. You can check the option in Crystal designer too.